# How to Speed up NOT IN or LEFT JOIN or NOT EXIST in Mysql Query

Tags: mysql

Hello everyone I am writing this query for Took Not Exist value(For Validation), I have 51000 records in table A, And in table B 36000 records

Query With Not Exist

```
 SELECT A.D_ID FROM temp_status_entry AS A WHERE A.Created_by ='1' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM status_entry AS B WHERE B.NoofLines ='0' AND A.D_ID = B.S_ID )
```

Query With LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT A.D_ID FROM temp_status_entry A LEFT JOIN status_entry B ON A.D_ID = B.S_ID WHERE A.D_ID IS NULL
```

Query With LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT D_ID FROM temp_status_entry WHERE Created_by ='1' AND D_ID NOT IN (SELECT S_ID FROM status_entry WHERE NoofLines ='0' )
```

All Takes more then 1000 sec Please Help me to solve this(I am using Navicat)
also try with indexes

Comment: For a fractional improvement, remove inverted commas around numerals. For further improvement, provide all relevant CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN statements

Comment: if you have only 51k and 36k rows it's almost impossible that it'll need 1k sec for this query. Have you checked the system load? Maybe you have some process that it's using 100% CPU or that it's reading a lot from disk. And the second query is wrong, it should be **B.S_ID IS NULL**

Comment: @TheOni ,Strawberry. Thanks Bro . TheOni Bro i try with  B.S_ID IS NULL and ti still running , mysqld.exe takes 30%

Comment: @Madhan can you add to your question the result of the execution of **EXPLAIN SELECT...** for the 3 query

Comment: It not giving result it still running more then 13600sec. I think i want to make a partition

Comment: @Madhan temp_status_entry.d_id and status_entry.s_id are indexed?

Comment: Yes i add index